# Admob Banner not Showing Properly in AndEngine Android, Half Ad is Displayed

Tags: admob, andengine, google-play-services

I am using Google Play Services Library to integrate admob in my app.
Admob is partially displaying but if I try to display someother banner that banner ad is properly displayed.
I am using AndEngine to develop the app.
Here is the screen shot of the banner which I added on the top.
[image]

Here is the XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/xmllayoutRenderSurfaceView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="top" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adslayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/adcrossingbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/adcrossingbtn"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is Java Code:

```
AdmobadView = new AdView(mact);
AdmobadView.setAdUnitId(AdmobID);
AdmobadView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
AdmobadView.loadAd(adRequest);
mBannerAddFramlayout.addView(AdmobadView);
```

Please help me solve this issues.
Thanks

Comment: Any solution for this ? I am facing the same problem :-/

Answer (score 0):

Provide a layoutHeight and LayoutWeight when you add your AdView to the FrameLayout.

And get rid of the ImageView.

Comment: Width and Height are provided as wrap content, I cant get rid of image view I need to show a button to close the ad.

Comment: ?? What do you mean btton to close the ad. The ad takes care of itself.

Comment: it means to make the ad invisible, admob banner doesn't have this functionality built in.